# how to get URL from new window

Tags: javascript, url, cross-domain

I want to get a new window URL by any languages
I tried this

```
//window opening from  a website example2.org
var myNewWindow = window.open("https://www.example1.org");
var myURL = myNewWindow.location.href;
```

But It is not working

It seems like a domain issue. I found that Javascrpit cannot get the new window URL if its domain different then other.

Please teach me a way to get URL between different domains.

Comment: At `javascript` at Question `"https://www.example1.org"` is passed to `window.open()`. Is a different `location.href` expected for value of `myURL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you enable cross domain requests in your side?

Access-Control-Allow-Origin